# Knockout nested components

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying build components with help of KO component binding, but i have a small problem with nested components.

The scenario is I have text-input component which has a label which also is a component.

```
<div data-bind="component:{name:'text-input', params:{data:$data, parent:$parent}}," class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <div data-bind="component:{name:'label', params:{}}"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-11">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value:value" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Label component has a JS and a template, template looks like below

```
<label data-bind="text:labelText"></label>
```

But I am getting an error `Multiple bindings (text and component) are trying to control descendant bindings of the same element`

I understand `<div class="col-sm-1">`element is already bound to text-input context. Now the question is how to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The `component` binding fills the content of the `<div>` with the component's template, wiping out whatever else might be inside (hence the error). One option would be to add another component binding inside the `text-input` component's template which would allow a componentName/componentParams to be passed in `{componentName: label, componentParams: labelParams}`. You could also look at [working with component child nodes](http://www.knockmeout.net/2015/02/knockout-3-3-released.html) added in Knockout 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Actually found the issue. It's kind of silly mistake.

My  registered component is `label` and in my label's template I have `<label>` HTML tag, but since `label` is also a component, KO was trying to bind label's template to label tag which resulted in error and recursive loop.